# Setting types of unbound variables in Prolog

Tags: prolog, prolog-defaulty

I'm trying to find a way to set the type of a variable before it has been bound to a value. Unfortunately, the `integer/1` predicate cannot be used for this purpose:

```
%This goal fails if Int is an unbound variable.
get_first_int(Int,List) :-
    integer(Int),member(Int,List),writeln(Int).
```

I wrote a predicate called `is_int` that attempts to check the type in advance, but it does not work as I expected. It allows the variable to be bound to an atom instead of an integer:

```
:- initialization(main).
%This prints 'a' instead of 1.
main :- get_first_int(Int,[a,b,c,1]),writeln(Int).

get_first_int(Int,List) :-
    is_integer(Int),member(Int,List).

is_integer(A) :- integer(A);var(A).
```

Is it still possible to set the type of a variable that is not yet bound to a value?

Answer (score 3):

In SWI-Prolog I have used `when/2` for similar situations. I really don't know if it is a good idea, it definitely feels like a hack, but I guess it is good enough if you just want to say "this variable can only become X" where X is `integer`, or `number`, or `atom` and so on.

So:

```
will_be_integer(X) :- when(nonvar(X), integer(X)).
```

and then:

```
?- will_be_integer(X), member(X, [a,b,c,1]).
X = 1.
```

But I have the feeling that *almost* always you can figure out a less hacky way to achieve the same. For example, why not just write:

```
?- member(X, [a,b,c,1]), integer(X).
```

???

Comment: replace `ground` by `nonvar`, or `will_be_integer(s(X))` will succeed conditionally

Answer (score 2):

## Specific constraints for integers

In addition to what Boris said, I have a recommendation for the particular case of **integers**: Consider using **CLP(FD) constraints** to express that a variable *must be* of type *integer*. To express only this quite general requirement, you can post a CLP(FD) constraint that *necessarily holds* for all integers.

For example:

```
?- X in inf..sup.
X in inf..sup.
```

From this point onwards, `X` can *only* be instantiated to an integer. Everything else will yield a *type error*.

For example:

```
?- X in inf..sup, X = 3.
X = 3.

?- X in inf..sup, X = a.
ERROR: Type error: `integer' expected, found `a' (an atom)
```

Declaratively, you can always replace a *type error* with *silent failure*, since no possible additional instantiation can make the program *succeed* if this error arises.

Thus, in case you prefer *silent failure* over this type error, you can obtain it with `catch/3`:

```
?- X in inf..sup, catch(X = a, error(type_error(integer,_),_), false).
false.
```

CLP(FD) constraints are tailor-made for integers, and let you express also further requirements for this specific domain in a convenient way.

## Case-specific advice

Let us consider your specific example of `get_first_int/2`. First, let us rename it to `list_first_integer/3` so that it is clear what each argument is, and also to indicate that we fully intend to use it *in several directions*, not just to "get", but also to *test* and ideally to *generate* lists and integers that are in this relation.

Second, note that this predicate is rather messy, since it impurely depends on the *instantiation* of the list and integer, a property which cannot be expressed in first-order logic but rather depends on something outside of this logic. If we accept this, then one quite straight-forward way to do what you *primarily* want is to write it as:

```
list_first_integer(Ls, I) :-
        once((member(I0, Ls), integer(I0))),
        I = I0.
```

This works as long as the *list* is sufficiently instantiated, which implicitly seems to be the case in your examples, but definitely *need not be the case* in general. For example, with *fully instantiated* lists, we get:

```
?- list_first_integer([a,b,c], I).
false.

?- list_first_integer([a,b,c,4], I).
I = 4.

?- list_first_integer([a,b,c,4], 3).
false.
```

In contrast, if the list is *not* sufficiently instantiated, then we have the following major problems:

```
?- list_first_integer(Ls, I).
nontermination
```

and further:

```
?- list_first_integer([X,Y,Z], I).
false.
```

*even though* a more specific instantiation *succeeds*:

```
?- X = 0, list_first_integer([X,Y,Z], I).
X = I, I = 0.
```

### Core problem: Defaulty representation

The core problem is that you are reasoning here about *defaulty* terms: A list element that is still a variable may *either* be instantiated to an integer *or* to any other term in the future. A clean way out is to design your data representation to *symbolically* distinguish the possible cases. For example, let us use the wrapper `i/1` to denote an *integer*, and `o/1` to denote any *other* kind of term. With this representation, we can write:

```
list_first_integer([i(I)|_], I).
list_first_integer([o(_)|Ls], I) :-
        list_first_integer(Ls, I).
```

Now, we get correct results:

```
?- list_first_integer([X,Y,Z], I).
X = i(I) ;
X = o(_12702),
Y = i(I) ;
X = o(_12702),
Y = o(_12706),
Z = i(I) ;
false.

?- X = i(0), list_first_integer([X,Y,Z], I).
X = i(0),
I = 0 ;
false.
```

And the other examples also still work, if we only use the clean data representation:

```
?- list_first_integer([o(a),o(b),o(c)], I).
false.

?- list_first_integer([o(a),o(b),o(c),i(4)], I).
I = 4 ;
false.

?- list_first_integer([o(a),o(b),o(c),i(4)], 3).
false.
```

The most general query now allows us to *generate* solutions:

```
?- list_first_integer(Ls, I).
Ls = [i(I)|_16880] ;
Ls = [o(_16884), i(I)|_16890] ;
Ls = [o(_16884), o(_16894), i(I)|_16900] ;
Ls = [o(_16884), o(_16894), o(_16904), i(I)|_16910] ;
etc.
```

The *price* you have to pay for this generality lies in these symbolic wrappers. As you seem to care about correctness and also about generality of your code, I consider this a bargain in comparison to more error prone defaulty approaches.

## Synthesis

Note that CLP(FD) constraints can be naturally used together with a clean representation. For example, to benefit from more finely grained *type errors* as explained above, you can write:

```
list_first_integer([i(I)|_], I) :- I in inf..sup.
list_first_integer([o(_)|Ls], I) :-
        list_first_integer(Ls, I).
```

Now, you get:

```
?- list_first_integer([i(a)], I).
ERROR: Type error: `integer' expected, found `a' (an atom)
```

Initially, you may be faced with a defaulty representation. In my experience, a good approach is to convert it to a clean representation as soon as you can, for the sake of the remainder of your program in which you can then distinguish all cases symbolically in such a way that no ambiguity remains.